# Apache Multiple Sub Domains With One IP Address

Tags: apache, subdomain, vhosts

This has probably been asked but I can't find a straight answer, or the ones I found don't work.

I have one domain **mydomain.com**, resolving to an IP; let's call it 8.8.8.8. The DNS settings also point two subdomains to that IP address with an A record. These are **dev.mydomain.com** and **staging.mydomain.com**. Both have an A-record pointing to 8.8.8.8.

On the server (8.8.8.8) I have two virtual hosts files. These are as follows:

**staging.mydomain.com.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  staging.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mydomain.com/staging/
</VirtualHost>
```

And...

**dev.mydomain.com.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  dev.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mydomain.com/dev/
</VirtualHost>
```

***The problem is:***

Regardless of whether I visit *http://staging.mydomain.com* or *http://dev.mydomain.com*, I always land on *staging.mydomain.com* (Apache serves these files).

I have restarted Apache and even the server. If I change the order of the .conf files so that dev is first, I always see that. Any suggestions would be so appreciated. Thanks!

---

### **update**

I find myself back at this problem again! If you *know* that your syntax is correct, you might have a bad symlink. Delete it and recreate again, restarting apache in-between. I just did this and it solved hours of head-scratching. On `CentOS` you can check your available vhosts with `httpd -S`

### **update 2**

I've also found this issue to exist when the apache **log** files for the virtual host don't exist, or aren't writable.

Comment: I have voted to re-open this question, because both the question and the answer are helpful. Besides this, questions about Apache are not off-topic on StackOverflow, and ServerFault is only for professional setups.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Sounds like you need to add [`NameVirtualHost` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost) to your configuration.

```
NameVirtualHost         *:80
```

Under some circumstances Apache may not be able to handle `*:80` VirtualHosts correctly. In those cases you should map VirtualHosts directly on specific IPs.

```
NameVirtualHost         8.8.8.8:80

<VirtualHost 8.8.8.8:80>
    ServerName  staging.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias stage.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mydomain.com/staging/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 8.8.8.8:80>
    ServerName  dev.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias development.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mydomain.com/dev/
</VirtualHost>
```

You can also run `apachectl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS` to see how Apache parses the VirtualHost configuration.

Update: As mentioned in the comments, usually you can just use `NameVirtualHost *:80`. So most of the time you can configure the virtual hosts as follows.

```
NameVirtualHost         *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  staging.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias stage.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mydomain.com/staging/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  dev.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias development.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mydomain.com/dev/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thx Ketola. At the end of my httpd.conf file, I have the following (where the vhosts are included) `NameVirtualHost *:80 [[new line]] Include /etc/httpd/sites-enabled/`

Comment: That should work then. Apache can be a bit picky with `*:80` at times, so you might want to try `8.8.8.8:80` instead to see if it works better. Also run `apachectl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS` to see how Apache parses your configuration files. Updated the answer to reflect these as well.

Comment: Thanks Ketola, tried that in both .conf files and the httpd.conf file but no cigar, although the order changes! The `apachectl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS` is very useful and shows that Apache is defining the dev server as the default and loading it first.

Comment: Very strange. The only other cause I can think of is a typo somewhere, but that's quite unlikely. Do you have a proxy or anything else in between that could mess up the `Host:` header in the request? The next step would be to set `LogLevel debug` in Apache, and/or do `telnet localhost 80` on the server and request for the document directly.

Comment: Thx anyway Ketola. Going to look at the domain DNS settings again.

Comment: Thank you for accepting the answer Jongosi. I'm sure you'll figure out the problem soon enough.

Comment: I had a similar issue...the `apachectl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS` command was the tell all: `[Mon May 20 23:51:08 2013] [warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 80, the first has precedence
`. Adding the `NameVirtualHost *:80` solved it

Comment: For googlerslike me use this: <VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.domain.tld
ServerAlias domain.tld *.domain.tld
DocumentRoot /www/domain
</VirtualHost>

Comment: I tried NameVirtualHost, but it is being deprecated. And it didn't work for me anyway.