# How to link subdirectories using subdomain? (VirtualHost, mod_rewrite, htaccess, DNS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, subdomain, virtualhost, subdirectory

I am using EC2 and Route 53 of AWS(amazon web service) and LAMP(Apache, MySQL, PHP) of Bitnami.

I am trying to run two wordpress sites independently:

```
 ...local_path/htdocs/subsite1
 ...local_path/htdocs/subsite2
```

I want to access these subsites using subdomain like following:

```
 subsite1.mydomain.com → ...local_path/htdocs/subsite1
 subsite2.mydomain.com → ...local_path/htdocs/subsite2
```

Moreover, I want to switch where "mydomain.com" and "www.mydomain.com" when I want to(maybe once or twice a year). Specifically, I want to switch between Case A and B when I need.

```
Case A :
 subsite1.mydomain.com -↘︎  
 mydomain.com ----------→ ...local_path/htdocs/subsite1
 www.mydomain.com ------↗︎

 subsite2.mydomain.com → ...local_path/htdocs/subsite2

Case B :
 subsite1.mydomain.com → ...local_path/htdocs/subsite1

 mydomain.com ----------↘︎ 
 www.mydomain.com ------→ ...local_path/htdocs/subsite2
 subsite2.mydomain.com -↗︎
```

I tried to combine DNS(AWS Route 53), VirtualHost, mod_rewrite and/or htaccess following several internet articles, but it was not successful, though I think there is several way to realize it.

What is the best way to resolve this, considering security and convenience? and How should I set them?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837978/apache-multiple-sub-domains-with-one-ip-address

Comment: [This one in particular](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#serveralias)

Comment: could be, but I think there is no mention about the case of switching "mydomain.com" and "www.mydomain.com" on the linked post. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I did not know that because it was my first question! I did it. Thanx!

Answer (score 1):

**(SELF-ANSWER)**

I resolved it using *VirtualHost*.

Especially in the case of "mydomain.com" and "www.mydomain.com", I used *ServerAlias*.

First of all, I registered A records for my server's ip:

```
mydomain.com. A XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
www.mydomain.com. A XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
subdomain1.mydomain.com. A XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
subdomain2.mydomain.com. A XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

Second, in the config file for VirtualHost, (in my case, .../apache2/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf)

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin email1@domainX.com
        DocumentRoot ...local_path/htdocs/subsite.mydomain.com/htdocs
        ServerName subsite1.mydomain.com
        ServerAlias subsite1.mydomain.com mydomain.com
        ErrorLog "logs/subsite1.mydomain.com-error_log"
        CustomLog "logs/subsite1.mydomain.com-acccess_log" common
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin email2@domainY.com
        DocumentRoot ...local_path/htdocs/subsite2.mydomain.com/htdocs
        ServerName subsite2.mydomain.com
        ServerAlias subsite2.mydomain.com www.mydomain2.com
        ErrorLog "logs/subsite2.mydomain.com-error_log"
        CustomLog "logs/subsite2.mydomain.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

It works great!

**Reference** (Koreaen articles about VirtualHost)

- http://techstory.kr/%EC%9B%B9%EC%84%9C%EB%B2%84-%EC%84%A4%EC%B9%98-%EB%B0%8F-subdomain-%EC%84%A4%EC%A0%95/
- http://susemi99.kr/379

Comment: Also, I modified _httpd.conf_ which has [prevented activation of _.htaccess_ files](http://serverfault.com/questions/203550/htaccess-is-ignored-even-though-virtualhost-has-allowoverride-all). changed `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All` for _...web_root/htdocs_ directory