# two sub domains, two apache servers, one physical server

Tags: apache, tomcat

I have two sub domains like https://prj1.xxx.com, https://prj2.xxx.com

I have two WAS(tomcat9) running each project like prj1, prj2 as ROOT on each WAS.

Is it possible to install two apache servers on a single physical server to handle the above two domains? or Do I need to install one apache server?

If so, What do I need to take a look at? virtual host??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache Multiple Sub Domains With One IP Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837978/apache-multiple-sub-domains-with-one-ip-address)

Comment: @Martheen your link seems to talk about one apache server to handle two subdomains. I want to know if it is possible on two apache servers on a single physical server. If not, then I have to use one apache server.

Comment: Why you need two apache servers? You can, but no real reason for that

Comment: @Martheen oh ok, so the most common case is to have one apache server and configure virtual hosts to handle two sub-domains??

Comment: Yeah, an instance of Apache would hog the port entirely so even if you setup two of them, all traffic still goes through one of them before you forward it